# SQL Server update in substring

Tags: sql-server

I have a `varbinary` column in the database. That contains data a long range of data in hex.

I use `substring` to select and display data.

```
SELECT TOP 100
    CHAR_KEY AS charid,
    USER_KEY AS userid,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,substring(char_data, 9, 16)) AS name,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 7, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS level,
    CONVERT(INT,substring(char_data, 25, 1)) AS type,
    CONVERT(INT, substring(char_data, 261, 1)) AS permission,
    guild_data.guild_name
FROM CHAR_DATA0
    inner join guild_data 
    on guild_key = 
        CONVERT(INT, 
                cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 33, 4)) as BINARY(4)))
WHERE CONVERT(INT, substring(char_data, 261, 1))=0x00 
ORDER BY level DESC
```

Now I want to `UPDATE`, any ideas? Thanks a lot. I'm new at this. I tried looking for a `substring` update but didn't find any working examples on the net.

Thanks.

-----edit-----

I tried this:

```
UPDATE
CHAR_TDATA0
SET char_data = stuff(cast(char_data as BINARY(2000)), 9, 16, CONVERT(BINARY(16), 'testnamezs'))
WHERE CHAR_KEY=4
```

But no luck. Got some syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding why you would want to save data this way, instead of using separate columns in the database for the various pieces of data.

In any case, I don't think you can update a part of the data that way. I think what you have to do is select all the data for a row, update the part you want to change, and then re-insert the updated string of hex-based data as a whole.

Something like:

```
UPDATE
CHAR_TDATA0
SET char_data = "your already hex-encoded string of data here..."
WHERE CHAR_KEY=4
```

Comment: Yes, your idea on the 2nd phrase is my original plan. I was trying to find out if there was any other way. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Try holding the contents in a SQL Server Variable first, calculate and then update.
Hope this helps.

```
DECLARE @lc_char_data as varchar(max)
SET @lc_char_data = stuff(cast(char_data as BINARY(2000)), 9, 16, CONVERT(BINARY(16), 'testnamezs'))
UPDATE
CHAR_TDATA0
SET char_data = @lc_char_data
WHERE CHAR_KEY=4
```